# ToolStripMenuSeparator prevents Disable/Enable programmatically of ToolStripMenuItems

Tags: vb.net

I am using this part of code below to disable some `ToolStripMenuItems` whose tag is `M2` for example. The problem is that code works, untill it "meets" the first `ToolStripMenuSeparator`. Even if `ToolStripMenuItems` under `ToolStripMenuSeparator` have `M2` as tag, remain enabled. If I manually remove the `ToolStripMenuSeparator` everything is okay!!! There is any difference in case we have a separator between menu items?

```
Dim MenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    For Each MenuItem In MainForm_MenuStrip.Items
        If (MenuItem.GetType() Is GetType(ToolStripMenuItem)) Then
            Dim MenuSubItem As ToolStripMenuItem
            For Each MenuSubItem In MenuItem.DropDownItems
                If (MenuSubItem.GetType() Is GetType(ToolStripMenuItem)) And MenuSubItem.Tag = "M2" Then
                    MenuSubItem.Enabled = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `ToolStripSeparator` can not be casted to `ToolStripMenuItem`.
So the following line will throw an `InvalidCastException` as soon as the loop reaches the `ToolStripSeparator`:

```
For Each MenuSubItem In MenuItem.DropDownItems
```

If you cast to `ToolStripItem` instead it will work fine.
Furthermore you should define `MenuItem` as `Object` instead, otherwise your code will fail as soon as there's a `ToolStripTextbox` or `ToolStripCombobox` in the menu. Also the `GetType`-parts can be replaced with `TypeOf`.

```
For Each MenuItem As Object In Mainform_MenuStrip.Items
    If TypeOf MenuItem Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
        For Each MenuSubItem As ToolStripItem In MenuItem.DropDownItems
            If TypeOf MenuSubItem Is ToolStripMenuItem AndAlso MenuSubItem.Tag = "M2" Then
                MenuSubItem.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

This example uses late-binding.

Following will also work with `Option Strict On`:

```
For Each MenuItem As ToolStripItem In Mainform_MenuStrip.Items
    If TypeOf MenuItem Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
        For Each MenuSubItem As ToolStripItem In DirectCast(MenuItem, ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems
            If TypeOf MenuSubItem Is ToolStripMenuItem AndAlso CStr(MenuSubItem.Tag) = "M2" Then
                MenuSubItem.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```